# Accessing foreach variable in HTML element with runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding

I have a UserControl which has a Property for a list of products which contain a list of photos. In the `.ascx` I have a `DIV` as a container for all the photos. This works as is right now.

```
<% foreach (var product in Products) { %>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-photos">
            <% foreach (var photo in product.Photos) { %>
                <img src="<%= photo.Url %>" alt="<%= product.Name %> Photo"/>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <!-- Other product markup/data here... -->
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I am now trying to hide the `DIV` if there are no photos. My idea was to make the "product-photos" `DIV` have a `runat="server"` and give it a `Visible` attribute. This doesn't work because it can't resolve my `product` variable which comes from my `foreach` loop. It appears that the `runat="server"` makes the variables from the `foreach` loops inaccessible which doesn't make sense because the loop must also be running on the server.

***Question:***
How can I access variables defined in a `foreach` loop inside an `.as*x` file when the element has a `runat="server"`? Is this even possible? If not, what is an alternative way of accomplishing what I want?

**ProductsControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class ProductsControl: UserControl
{
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
{
    public IList<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    // Other properties here...
}
```

Comment: There was an answer posted a minute ago about using a `asp:DataList` instead of the foreach loop. I tryed to comment on it, but it was deleted before I could. Whoever added the answer and then deleted it should bring it back, it might actually help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not check the Count of the Photos before you create the div?

```
<% foreach (var product in Products) { %>
    <div class="product">
        <% if (product.Photos.Count > 0) { %>
            <div class="product-photos">
                <% foreach (var photo in product.Photos) { %>
                <img src="<%= photo.Url %>" alt="<%= product.Name %> Photo"/>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        <% } %> 
        <!-- Other product markup/data here... -->
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: This answer made me face-palm at myself. Why didn't I think of this? Thanks for your help! This is how I ended up hiding the photos DIV and the rest of the data which doesn't have values. My markup is pretty ugly now but it does the job.

Comment: LOL. Glad to be of assistance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the `<div>` by testing the `Count` of photo and setting the css style of it:

```
<div class="product-photos" style="<%= product.Photos.Count == 0 ? "display=none;" : "" %> ">
```

This will still create the `<div>` but it will but "hidden" on the page.

**EDIT:** To your question about using a managed control, like an `asp:Panel` which will render a `<div>`. You would have to dynamically create the controls during the [User Control Load event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load.aspx) based on the data that you've retrieved which would involve adding `child controls` on your user control.

Comment: I had thought of this solution as well; just adding a `display: none;` as a style if there are no photos. This will solve the specific problem I am having but is more of a 'work-around'. I still wonder if there is actually a way of getting the foreach variables in a `runat"server"` element because there is probably more use cases for needed it than just mine. Thanks though!

Comment: I believe the short answer for what you're asking is "no". Managed controls can't access server-side scripting variables for things like setting property values. The best you can do with server-side scripting is to render html controls using scripting variables. Otherwise you'd have to use a managed control and dynamically create them.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I have decided to go with your solution for now. I want to give the question a bit more time for people to read and potentially answer. If nothing better gets posted though, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon you could try using jquery to handle this for you, something like this maybe:

```
 $(function() {
      $('.product-photos').each(function() {
           var div = $(this);
           if ($(div).find('img').length === 0)
                div.hide();
      });
 });
```

This has not been tested but I believe that it should get you going.