# How to write inline C# code within html im asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website in asp.net so I want to write c# code within html pages but I dont know how to do this .I know I should use this "<% %>"  to use C# code but I want more help .please correct below code

Asp.net within html but it does not work

```
<% System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-B7KQDP5\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=Rishmak;Integrated Security=True");
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from indexinfo", sqlc);
            sqlc.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {%>
           <div class="dr["classs"].ToString();">
               <img src="../images/ dr["img"].ToString();" alt="Alternate Text" />dr["onvan"].ToString();
            <div style=" height:25px"></div>
            <div class="column-center-text bounceIn animated">
               dr["matn"].ToString();
            </div>
            <div><a href="#" class="btn">بیشتر بدانید</a></div>
        </div>
            }%>
```

Comment: See [Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Forms Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) for the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net how to write c# code inside aspx page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926428/asp-net-how-to-write-c-sharp-code-inside-aspx-page)

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms is not smart enough to know what's HTML and what's code without you telling it. You're approaching this from a classic ASP/PHP/ColdFusion direction. You should look up some beginner tutorials for ASP.NET to learn the proper way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but that looks like ASP.NET to me... Notice the use of of the asp:Image tag there. Basically what you're looking at is HTML with an ASP.NET control embedded in it.

You're looking at ASP.NET code, but I suggest you look at a tutorial to get the fundamentals and basics down. [Getting Started with ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you approach the issue with the old asp logic. In asp.Net, you don't have to put your codes inside the HTML tags, instead you should create asp .net objects and play with them from codebehind.

In your case, Repeater object would do the trick. Please check the link below:

[Repeater Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx)

With that, you can put the code you want to repeat inside the repeater and let the asp.net logic repeat it as you want, with the different parameters.

Comment: Of course you can, you can also control html objects from codebehind as well if necessary. Add runat="server" code to any html object and it will be shown as an asp.net object.

Comment: Mr Necati !. Please help me more.I think you Know More about my question.Please give mo more sample

Answer (score -1):

```
<% 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-B7KQDP5\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=Rishmak;Integrated Security=True");

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from indexinfo", sqlc);
            sqlc.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            { %>
           <div class="<% Response.Write(dr["classs"]); %>">
               <img src="../images/<% Response.Write(dr["img"]); %>" alt="Alternate Text" /><% Response.Write(dr["onvan"]); %>
            <div style=" height:25px"></div>
            <div class="column-center-text bounceIn animated">
               <% Response.Write(dr["matn"]); %>
            </div>
            <div><a href="#" class="btn">بیشتر بدانید</a></div>
        </div>
<%
            }%>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low quality. While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)